# How can I inject data into Google Slides from Google Sheet? Append List or Direct Function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to take data from Gsheet (city names tab in [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/123nNUk9u3O3R4FkbUpeRJFOpZK8RMR6BqvHOOnkWYC4/edit?usp=sharing)), and feed directly this data into some slides in Gslides, following [this template](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1CcwiZAQK7sj7XyyNhaFeTUcR9sL7CUo0I0phDY5XmeQ/edit?usp=sharing) for example.

In Gsheet, data is in the same range on each tabs, with the same header. The only thing that changes is the tab name. So [tab name]."{aaa}" for example, in which "{aaa}" would always be in the same range.

The Gslide template would "receive" this data from Gsheet, and pick up the data from either:

- an appended list following the [tab name]."{header}" model.
- directly without creating this appended list if I manage to create a function following the [tab name]."{header}" model.

The End product would be a file in which users can add tabs in the Gsheet file, following the template (ie a city name and the same data in the same range) and feed Gslides through the template, in which they could enter the text they want, following the [tab name].{header} model.

My questions are as follow:

- Which method would be the best and less resources hungry?
- if I choose the list method, How can I append a list from Gsheet using the range from all my tabs that would then be used in the script from Gslide?
- How can I write a function in Gscript in order to populate the data in the slides I will be creating?

I've started writing the folllowing code with help from stackoverflow, but I'm struggling in:

- The order in which I have to do things
- Obviously the function for either the Appended List model / the [tab name]."{header}" model

```
var NARRATIVE_SHEETS_URL ='xxx' // the URL of the Gsheet where the data is from
var SHEET_NAME = 'xxx' // this would be each tabs name;

function replaceMetric(pages) {
  var text_vals = getAutoValue(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
     var page = pages[i];
     replaceTextByAutoVal(page, text_vals);
  }
}

function replaceSelectedSlides() {
  var selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();  
  var selectionType = selection.getSelectionType();
  if (selectionType == SlidesApp.SelectionType.PAGE) {
    var pageRange = selection.getPageRange();
    var pages = pageRange.getPages();
    replaceMetric(pages);
  }
}

function replaceTextByAutoVal(slide, text_vals) {
  slide.replaceAllText("{aaa}", text_vals[0][0]);
  slide.replaceAllText("{bbb}", text_vals[1][0]);
  slide.replaceAllText("{ccc}", text_vals[2][0]);
  slide.replaceAllText("{ddd}", text_vals[3][0]);
  Logger.log("Replacement done");
} // This is the data that will always be in the same range for each tabs

function getAutoValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(NARRATIVE_SHEETS_URL);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets() ;
  var valList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        var sheet = sheets[i];

        Logger.log(sheet.getSheetName());
        const ignoreTabs = ["Presentation", "Start", "End", "Raw Data"];  // Tab names I want to ignore.
        if (ignoreTabs.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
          // do nothing
        } else {
          // do something
          Logger.log("found");
          var range = sheet.getRange("D3:D6");
          var values = range.getValues();
          valList.append(values);
          Logger.log(values)
          return values;
        }
  }  

}
```

Comment: I'd say your question is too broad, it should focus on a single specific issue. I'd focus on inserting the text to the slide, however you decide it to be inserted. In that sense, can you visually clarify how should the data be structured and displayed in the slides?

Comment: I will have a Excel datasheet that gets refreshed weekly, similar to this one, in which user will have the possibility to add tabs related to their city: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/123nNUk9u3O3R4FkbUpeRJFOpZK8RMR6BqvHOOnkWYC4/edit?usp=sharing

As per the Data displayed in the slides, it will be something like this, in which users will have the possibility to inject data as they see fit, following the [tab name].{header} model https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1CcwiZAQK7sj7XyyNhaFeTUcR9sL7CUo0I0phDY5XmeQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, so in this example, the idea would be to just replace e.g. `[Paris].{aaa}` with `8000` and so on? The rest of the elements in the presentation (the slide with the text boxes, etc.) would be created already? And it should look for the `[tab_name].{header}` model in every slide of the presentation?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help !

Yeah, the idea is exactly that, e.g. replace `[Paris].{aaa}` with `8000` in that example. I will create the template(s) in Gslide, and what I wanted to do was to feed those templates with whatever `[tab_name].{header}` it would find from the Gsheet data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

When retrieving the data for each sheet, format it so that it matches the placeholder values, interpolating the sheet name and the header:

```
[tab_name].{header}
```

This can be done the following way (see [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)):

```
const sheetData = values.map(row => [`[${sheetName}].{${row[0]}}`, row[1]]);
```

Once you have that, it's just a matter of using [Presentation.replaceAllText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#replaceAllText(String,String)) for each header.

Also, you are only grabbing column `D`; you should retrieve column `E` too, like `D5:E8`.

#### Code sample:

```
function replaceSheetDataInSlides() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(NARRATIVE_SHEETS_URL);
  const sheets = ss.getSheets() ;
  const valList = [];
  const ignoreTabs = ["Presentation", "Start", "End", "Raw Data"];  // Tab names I want to ignore.
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    const sheet = sheets[i];
    const sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (!ignoreTabs.includes(sheetName)) {
      const range = sheet.getRange("D5:E8");
      const values = range.getValues();
      const sheetData = values.map(row => [`[${sheetName}].{${row[0]}}`, row[1]]);
      valList.push(...sheetData);
    }
  }
  const pres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  valList.forEach(value => pres.replaceAllText(value[0], value[1]));
}
```

Comment: You must hear this quite often, but you're a genius !!! Thank you so much for your help.